# Installing "xyz firmware" vs Rooting on "xyz firmware".

Tags: rooting, updates, installation, device-firmware

What's the difference between rooting on a particular firmware and installing a particular firmware?

Does that mean to root on "xyz" you must have installed "xyz" on your device?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says:

- "root on XYZ" means XYZ is a pre-condition for this rooting instructions (so yes, it must already be on the device)
- "install XYZ" means, well, to install XYZ (whether it already was on the device or not).

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes it's the simple things which confuse us most :)

Comment: You're right :)